# SQL Query to Join 2 sets of results by year

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

SQL Question:

I have this query:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date) AS month, Year(getdate()) AS Year, COUNT(*) AS monthly_sales_count
FROM orders
WHERE status = 0
AND YEAR(date) = 2012
GROUP BY month;
```

Which gives me results for 2012 per month.

How can I add the results for 2011 in one set of data, so i would get something like this:

```
Month       Year       Monthly_sales_count
december    2012        6576
november    2012        8788
october     2012        7676
september   2012          56
august      2012         345
july        2012        3356
june        2012        6563
may         2012        3245 
april       2012       25234
march       2012         234
february    2012         454
january     2012       24352
december    2011        6576
november    2011        8788
october     2011        7676
september   2011        1313
august      2011        1343
july        2011        2243
june        2011         656
may         2011        3234
april       2011      435345
march       2011       34345
february    2011        2134
january     2011        3412
```

Comment: us union with another query providing input as 2011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date) AS month, Year(date) AS Year, COUNT(*) AS monthly_sales_count
FROM orders
WHERE status = 0
AND YEAR(date) IN (2011, 2012)
GROUP BY month, year
ORDER BY year, month;
```

Though I'd look to make the WHERE clause sargable (make use of index)

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date) AS month, Year(date) AS Year, COUNT(*) AS monthly_sales_count
FROM orders
WHERE status = 0
    AND date >= '20110101' AND date < '20130101'
GROUP BY month, year;
```

**NOTE:**
You were doing `YEAR(GETDATE())`, whereas I've assumed you actually want to do `YEAR(date)` - if what you had was deliberate, then will need more info on exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date) AS month, Year(getdate()) AS Year, 
                COUNT(*) AS monthly_sales_count
FROM orders
WHERE status = 0
AND YEAR(date) = 2012
GROUP BY month
union
SELECT MONTHNAME(date) AS month, Year(getdate()) AS Year, 
                COUNT(*) AS monthly_sales_count
FROM orders
WHERE status = 0
AND YEAR(date) = 2011
GROUP BY month;
```

Comment: Downside comes if you want more than 2 years, it soon becomes unwieldy. Plus UNION will apply a DISTINCT - wherever possible and appropriate, so favour UNION ALL here.

Comment: I don't see how having multiple queries unioned is better than one with a larger `WHERE` clause.